# Caching API data, should I serialize the data into a single column? Or other approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I am implementing a Twitter app, where the app needs to cache details of users coming from Twitter. Would it be wise to serialize the data into a column called `data`? Or, in my User model, should I create a column for each field that is returned by the [API request](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/account/verify_credentials)?

Reading about [(ActiveRecord::Base) serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize).

If I go with the latter approach, I would end up with a lot of fields in my User model and if the Twitter API decides to add or remove fields in the future, then we would have to update our columns in our db respectively.

However, one advantage I can think of with this approach, is if each column was stored in the db. I could say, search for all twitter users based on location. I could also index the `location` column for faster queries. How does this compare to the serialized approach?

One will suggest: **"Don't search serialized data, just don't do it"**.

So I guess, I can have two columns: `data` (for serialized data), and `location`, no?

But lets add a few more twists:

1. The app needs to sort users out by registered date. Not with our app, but with Twitter.
2. The app should be able to search users by Twitter screen name or Twitter id.
3. The app should be able to sort users out by followers, friends and statuses count.

Does this mean, I would need 8 columns in my db: `data`, `location`, `twitter_created_at`, `twitter_screen_name`, `twitter_id`, `followers_count`, `friends_count` and `statuses_count`? At this point, would it still be better to go for a mix-column-type approach, or just single each field to its own column.

Would you save the data returned from the API into a single column: `data`, or save each field in its own respective column, or have a mix of both (as described above)?

Your thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider creating an associate table for this, that has user id, name and value columns. Then you can have a one to many relationship to store those fields. In the future if the valid set of fields changes you simple add or remove rows to this table that are associated with the user.

Comment: Jaydel, not sure I get you. Do you think you can provide a sample for this to better illustrate your suggestion?

Comment: yes, I'll put it in an answer so I get the formatting...

Comment: Great, looking forward to it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assume for a moment that you have a table with the following three columns:

```
user_id, api_field_name, api_field_value
```

In this table you can add a row for each api field you want to persist. For example:

```
user_d     api_field_name        api_field_value
1          "meaning_of_life"     42
1          "swallow_type"        "africa"
```

This means that user number 1 has these two custom parameters that are tied to the api...if the api changes later on and "swallow_type" is removed, you can get rid of that row. New api fields can be added on the fly.

This is an easy way to handle custom parameters that can and do change periodically. It saves you from having to restructure a table each time the api changes.

This is the point where I duck to avoid the incoming flak from DB purists...

Comment: Interesting solution. Let's say the Twitter API returns 20 fields. This means every single user is associated with 20 fields in this table? If i have 500k users signed up, thats 500*20 5,000,000,000 records alone in this table just for holding API data? Yipes! Another concern is, what happens when I need to update, remove or add a new field name. I would have to go through 5,000,000,000 rows just to update the fields? Will this have any performance drawbacks?

Comment: it could. perhaps some aggressive indexing would bring that down, but yes that's a lot of rows to manage. in light of that, it might be better to serialize the data (JSON seems like an interesting idea), but I've always resisted that approach because if you ever need to look up users by one or more of the things in this serialization you'll likely find even more pain. But if all you ever do is load them up, parse them and then apply them, then serialization isn't a horrible idea. I always try to avoid this approach, but I'm also a firm believer in "breaking" rules when needed.